# want to calculate values of new columns by picking up the formula defined in another column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df with n number of columns calculated dynamically. in that df it has one column which defines that what formula i need to apply to calculate values of another new column. That formula need to be applied on the existing columns of that df

For example:
df1

```
Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4(Formula)        Col5(Calculatedby executingformulain Col4
2017  12   2    Col2/col3            6
2018  14   7    Col2*Col3            98
```

So what i want that whatever formula is written in Col4 that will be performed on existing columns as given so that new values can be calculated of col5 at each row

Comment: Well it wont be easy if there are typos on your Col4(Formula) values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`df.eval()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
df['Col5']=np.diag(df.eval(df['Col4(Formula)']))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4(Formula) Col5
0  2017    12     2     Col2/Col3    6
1  2018    14     7     Col2*Col3   98
```

Comment: Note: This is assuming that formula column is `Col2/Col3` and not `Col2/col3` which I assumed as a typo

Comment: thank anky_91 it is wroking fine in my df thank you ver much